# Strapi + Heroku deployment failed:npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, strapi

**Goal:**

To have my strapi server deployed to heroku, so I can have a headless CMS.

**Error:**

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^cd s": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.1tJNV/_logs/2019-11-19T14_12_00_784Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

**System:**

- Node.js version: 12.13.0
- NPM version: 6.12.0
- Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.17.4
- Database: MongoDB atlas cloud
- Operating system: LinuxMint 19.2 Cinnamon
- Front-end : React 16.11.0

**I have tried:**

[Strapi heroku deployment guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#heroku)

[Heroku trouble shooting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)

**Question:**

Now I ran out of trials to experiment with...what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, heroku has git conflict with my server folder which is inside my react project folder. I moved my strapi server folder outside and git init and deployed again, this time it works.

UPDATE: I also found the error, it was in my react package.json file in the dependencies for strapi. I have no idea how that ended up there!